# How long it took the initial sync drbd with a 6TB raid

Tags: drbd

I created a two node drbd drive and creating the initial synchronization of distributed file system drbd, this taking days. It is a raid5 with 3 disks 3TB each, creating a 6TB raid which mirrored by drbd replicate on another computer.
The issue is that it takes five days to the initial synchronization. Network cards are 1GB and drbd.conf configuration file in "Syncer" with the parameter "rate" was 100MB.
It is normal to take so long.

Answer (score 4):

You've left out a lot of pieces.

What's your link speed between the drbd nodes?

How fast can you write to your drives?

You're probably only able to write to the arrays at a sustained rate of around 100Mbps (be it because of a 100Mbps link or the fact that you can't write to the drives faster than that).

[6TB/100Mbps](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6TB%2F100Mbps) == 480000 seconds == 5.556 days

Sounds right to me.